# magento 2 - first order dicount

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Is there any way to give a customer coupon code for first order only ? ( in cause second order for customer can't use the coupon even if Its not use it in first order)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow using customer segment for that refer this:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rule-discount-first-purchase.html

You can create a customer segment and use it on the cart rule.

Also if you are using community edition you can still create a cart rule but need to add custom rule conditions you can refer this https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-custom-sales-rule-condition/ you can change logic with customer total order count

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately conditions not help enough to detected if this is a first order or second because i don't want customer to user discount in second order even if not using it in first order.